# Find Number of Records Higher Than A Specific Number In Other Table

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have two tables with following structure:
First Table:

```
ID    Name    Total_courses_allowed
1     Ahmad     4
2     Khan      3
3     Mahmood   2
```

Second Table:

```
ID   Course_attended   emp_id
1           f             1
2           t             1  
3           f             1
4           t             1
5           f             2
6           t             2
7           t             2
8           f             3
9           f             3
10          t             1
11          f             1
12          t             2
13          f             2
```

For each record in first table there should be as many records as their total_courses allowed in second table. but for some of the records it is created more than that their allowed number of courses to attend like for, ID 1 of first table 6 rows are generated in second table whereas it should be only 4.

I need a SQL query to find all the records which have more entries in the second table than their total allowed courses to attend.

Thanks,

Comment: I recommend you update your question to include the result set that you're expecting; also, what query(s) have you tried so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry if it is not well formatted but I'm on mobile.

You can get it by counting attended courses and getting those records where total is lower.

```
select id, name, total_couses_allowed
from table1
inner join (select emp_id, count(*) as courses
            from table2
            where course_attended = 't'
            group by emp_id) t2
on table1id = t2.emp_id
where total_courses_allowed < courses
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, name, Total_courses_allowed ,t2.real_Course_attended
from FirstTable t1
inner join (select emp_id, count(emp_id) as courses ,count(Course_attended) real_Course_attended
            from SecondTable
            where course_attended = 't'
            group by emp_id,Course_attended) t2
on t1.id = t2.emp_id
where t1.Total_courses_allowed >t2.courses;
```